# Monthly Aggregation in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking for a way to aggregate by month my data. I want firstly to keep only month in my visitdate. My DataFrame looks like this:

```
Row(visitdate = 1/1/2013, 
patientid = P1_Pt1959, 
amount = 200, 
note = jnut, 
)
```

My objectif subsequently is to group by visitdate and calculate the sum of amount. I tried this :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
.config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
.getOrCreate()

file_path = "G:/Visit Data.csv"
patients = spark.read.csv(file_path,header = True)
patients.createOrReplaceTempView("visitdate")

sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT visitdate,SUM(amount) as totalamount from visitdate GROUP BY visitdate")
sqlDF.show()
```

This is the result :

```
visitdate|totalamount|
+----------+-----------+
|  9/1/2013|    10800.0|
|25/04/2013|    12440.0|
|27/03/2014|    16930.0|
|26/03/2015|    18560.0|
|14/05/2013|    13770.0|
|30/06/2013|    13880.0
```

My objectif is to get something like this:

```
  visitdate|totalamount|
+----------+-----------+
|1/1/2013|    10800.0|
|1/2/2013|    12440.0|
|1/3/2013|    16930.0|
|1/4/2014|    18560.0|
|1/5/2015|    13770.0|
|1/6/2015|    13880.0|
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group spark dataframe by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946051/group-spark-dataframe-by-date)

Answer (score 3):

You could [format](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_format) `visitdate` first and then do the group by:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df.withColumn('visitdate_month', F.date_format(F.col('visitdate'), '1/M/yyyy'))
.groupBy('visitdate_month')
.agg(F.sum(F.col('visitdate_month')))
)
```

Comment: getting null data in the middel
visitdate_month| count|
+---------------+------+
|     2014-08-01|   241|
|     2015-04-01|   245|
|     2014-11-01|   247|
|     2014-09-01|   246|
|     2013-08-01|   187|
|     2015-02-01|   269|
|     2014-05-01|   277|
|           null|204363|
|     2015-06-01|   260|
|     2015-03-01|   242|
|     2013-12-01|   181|

Comment: Sorry, you have to convert from your string to date and then to the other string format. See my updated answer.

Comment: this time entire data coming null
+---------------+--------------------+
|visitdate_month|sum(visitdate_month)|
+---------------+--------------------+
|      1/01/2013|                null|
+---------------+--------------------+

Comment: I updated my answer. `date_format` can parse a date and the convert it to your format.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like column "visitdate" type is String, can be converted to Timestamp with "unix_timestamp", and then to String in required format with "date_format". After this, grouping can be performed, on Scala:

```
val visitMonthDf = df.withColumn("visitMonth", date_format(unix_timestamp($"visitdate", "dd/MM/yyyy").cast(TimestampType), "1/M/yyyy"))
visitMonthDf.groupBy("visitMonth").agg(sum($"totalamount"))
```

Comment: Note: The question is tagged with python

Comment: Guess, can be translated to Python by question author.