# What is the best way to extract time resolution from timestamp for specific value in column?

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have the following Spark frame:

```py
+--------------------------+-----+
|timestamp                 |name |
+--------------------------+-----+
|2021-11-06 16:29:00.004204|Alice|
|2021-11-06 16:29:00.004204|Bob  |
+--------------------------+-----+
```

now I want to extract count value of records/rows based on timestamp for specific `name == 'Alice'` as follows :

- 1st 12-hrs working shift   (00:00-11:59:59)
- 2nd 12-hrs working shift   (12:00-23:59:59)
- 1st 8-hrs working shift (00:00-07:59:59)
- 2nd 8-hrs working shift (08:00-15:59:59)
- 3rd 8-hrs working shift (16:00-23:59:59)

and return back the results to the Spark frame. I have tried the following approach unsuccessfully:

```py
import time
import datetime as dt
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import dayofmonth, dayofweek
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType, TimestampType

dict = [{ 'name': 'Alice'},
        { 'name': 'Bob'}]
#df = spark.createDataFrame(dict)
schema = StructType([ 
    StructField("timestamp",        TimestampType(), True), \
    StructField("date",             StringType(), True), \
    StructField("name",            StringType(), True), \
  ])
 
#create a Spark dataframe
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
sdf = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data=dict,schema=schema)
sdf.printSchema()
sdf.show(truncate=False)

#Generate data and timestamp
new_df = sdf.withColumn('timestamp',    F.current_timestamp().cast("timestamp")) \
            .withColumn('date',         F.current_date().cast("date")) \
            .withColumn('day_of_month', dayofmonth('timestamp')) \
            .withColumn('day_of_week', ((dayofweek('timestamp')+5)%7)+1)  # start of the week as a Monday = 1 (by default is Sunday = 1)
            #.withColumn("No. records in 1st 12-hrs",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("timestamp"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),"HH:mm:ss")) \
            #.filter(col("timestamp").between("00:00","11:59")) \
            #.groupBy("No. records in 1st 12-hrs", "name").sum("Count") \
            #.withColumn("No. records in 1st 12-hrs",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("timestamp"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),"HH:mm:ss")) \
            #.filter(col("timestamp").between("12:00","23:59")) \
            #.groupBy("No. records in 1st 12-hrs" , "name").sum("Count") \

            #.withColumn('# No. records in 1st 8-hrs shift (00:00-07:59:59)', ????('timestamp')) \
            #.withColumn('# No. records in 2nd 8-hrs shift (08:00-15:59:59)', ????('timestamp')) \
            #.withColumn('# No. records in 3rd 8-hrs shift (16:00-23:59:59)', ????('timestamp')) \
new_df.show(truncate = False)
```

so until now, my output is as below which you can try in [Colab notebook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10TUXAKBLCQgnoXNpHELxziwq9WS4m2Ui/view?usp=sharing):

```
+--------------------------+----------+-----+------------+-----------+
|timestamp                 |date      |name |day_of_month|day_of_week|
+--------------------------+----------+-----+------------+-----------+
|2021-11-06 16:17:43.698815|2021-11-06|Alice|6           |6          |
|2021-11-06 16:17:43.698815|2021-11-06|Bob  |6           |6          |
+--------------------------+----------+-----+------------+-----------+
```

alternatively, I checked some post for [Spark based data filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994997/filtering-a-spark-dataframe-based-on-date)  as well as a cool [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47897373/10452700) and [Group spark dataframe by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946051/group-spark-dataframe-by-date) to apply on main spark frame for specific `name` besides working shift range.

Please note that I'm not interested in using `UDF` or hacking it via `toPandas()`

so expected results should be like that for specific `name == 'Alice'`:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|No. records in 1st 12-hrs |No. records in 1st 12-hrs |No. records in 1st 8-hrs  |No. records in 2nd 8-hrs  |No. records in 3rd 8-hrs  |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|                          |                          |                          |                          |                          |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by checking the hour part of the timestamps is between `[0, 11]`, `[12, 23]` and so on...

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

new_df = sdf.groupBy("name").agg(
    F.sum(F.hour("timestamp").between(0, 11).cast("int")).alias("1st-12-hrs"),
    F.sum(F.hour("timestamp").between(12, 23).cast("int")).alias("2nd-12-hrs"),
    F.sum(F.hour("timestamp").between(0, 7).cast("int")).alias("1st-8-hrs"),
    F.sum(F.hour("timestamp").between(8, 15).cast("int")).alias("2nd-8-hrs"),
    F.sum(F.hour("timestamp").between(16, 23).cast("int")).alias("3rd-8-hrs"),
)

new_df.show()

#+-----+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
#|name |1st-12-hrs|2nd-12-hrs|1st-8-hrs|2nd-8-hrs|3rd-8-hrs|
#+-----+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
#|Bob  |0         |1         |0        |0        |1        |
#|Alice|0         |1         |0        |0        |1        |
#+-----+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
```